# Bypassing "OR" SQLi filter

Tags: sql-injection, waf

I am trying to bypass a filter on a black-box SQL injection CTF that likely looks like `/or/i`. I suspect the filter is in a WAF somewhere in between me and the target.

To get the `OR` keyword, I use `||`.

Instead of using the `ORD()` function, I use `ASCII()`.

But the DBMS is MySQL, how can I use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` which contains "OR" as a substring as part of a statement such as `SELECT ... FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables`?

I tried bypassing the WAF via other ways but without success:

- URL-encoding
- Double URL-encoding
- UTF-8 encoding

Comment: This is pure programming question and is off topic on Security SE.

Comment: What make you think there is a WAF? A specific HTTP status code or response? It's very possible and even likely there is one, then try to confirm this hypothesis, and even better try to identify the WAF in question. Perhaps you can then research the limitations of that particular WAF to bypass them.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: if the MySQL version is recent enough (>5.5) and the user has enough privileges, it is possible to use the `mysql.innodb_table_stats` or `mysql.innodb_table_stats` tables ([source](https://osandamalith.com/2017/02/03/alternative-for-information_schema-tables-in-mysql/)) to retreive table names:

```
select table_name from mysql.innodb_table_stats where database_name=schema();
```